# php csrf protection library

Tags: php, csrf

Are there any libraries to protect against CSRF(PHP5.1/5.2) or do I need to create on myself? I use this snippet from [Chris](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries), but without a library I am getting a lot of duplication on every page.

I found this [library](http://www.brankovukelic.com/post/2149481881/csrf4php-gpl-cross-site-request-forgery-protection) for PHP5.3, but I am wondering if there are any on PHP5.1/5.2 because I don't believe yet all hosting support PHP5.3.

Comment: It is easy to write it yourself.

Comment: @zerkms I already started doing that, but you should reuse software if possible..

Comment: @Alfred: it is: 1) one small function to generate random token and store it in session 2) one small helper to paste hidden field 3) one small function to validate. It doesn't worth to look for something ready and waste time to adapt it to your infrastructure.

Comment: @zerkms You are a little bit right about that, but also it takes time and if there is a library then other people can safe that time if you ask me!

Comment: @Alfred: you asked this question 3 hours ago. During this time it was possible to implement it from scratch triple at least ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I know that :P. But still it would be useful if it was freely available. Do you have such library. If you have, please post code online on github as gist or something :P

Comment: @Alfred: since I use Kohana for my own projects, I've just extended couple of its classes: http://pastebin.com/FGtE8eA8

Comment: @zerkms post as question and I will accept it as answer :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I use Kohana - I've just extended couple of its core classes. It can be used in any code with a little changes though:

```
class Form extends Kohana_Form
{
  public static function open($action = NULL, array $attributes = null)
  {
      if (is_null($action))
      {
          $action = Request::current()->uri . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '');
      }

    $open = parent::open($action, $attributes);
    $open .= parent::hidden(self::csrf_token_field(), self::csrf_token());
    return $open;
  }

  public static function csrf_token_field()
  {
    return 'csrf_token';
  }

  public static function csrf_token()
  {
    $session = Session::instance();
    $token = $session->get(self::csrf_token_field());

    if (!$token)
    {
      $session->set(self::csrf_token_field(), $token = md5(uniqid()));
    }

    return $token;
  }
}

class Validate extends Kohana_Validate
{
    public function __construct(array $array, $csrf = true)
    {
        parent::__construct($array);
        if ($csrf)
            $this->add_csrf();
    }

    public static function factory(array $array, $csrf = true)
    {
        return new Validate($array, $csrf);
    }

    private function add_csrf()
    {
        $this->rules(form::csrf_token_field(), array(
            'not_empty' => array(),
            'csrf' => array()
        ));
    }

    protected function csrf($token)
    {
        return $token == form::csrf_token();
    }

}
```